# Angular $resource - accessing to returned resource.$promise in TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-resource

I'need to access the `$promise` property of object returned with some default action on `$resource` (e.g. remove, query...). But it seems it is not possible in current TypeScript definitions for `$resource`:

Example:

I have a student resource:

```
interface IStudentDataModel {
    name: string
    age: number
}

interface IStudentResource extends IResourceClass<IStudentDataModel> {
    deactivate(params: Object): IResource<IStudentDataModel>
}


export default function ($resource: IResourceService, CONFIG: IConfig): IStudentResource {
    "ngInject"

    let deactivateAction: IActionDescriptor = {
        url: `${CONFIG.api_host}/students/:studentId/deactivate`,
        method: 'PUT'
    }

    return <IStudentResource>$resource(
        `${CONFIG.api_host}/students/:studentId`,        
    }
        studentId: '@studentId'    
    },
    {
        deactivate: deactivateAction,
    });

}
```

Then I'm using this resource in another service:

```
export default class StudentActions {
    constructor(
        private StudentResource: IStudentResource,
    ) {
        "ngInject"
    }

    deactivate(studentId: number): IPromise<any> {
        return this.StudentResource.deactivate({ studnetId: studentId}).$promise;
    }

    remove(studentId: number): IPromise<any> {
        return this.StudentResource.remove({ studentId: studentId}).$promise; //!!!           
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: I can't access to the `this.StudentResource.remove({ studentId: studentId}).$promise` because default actions have `IStudentDataModel` as return trype instead of `IResource<IStudentDataModel>` (but it returns resource with $promise property, not only data model).

I've tried to override the remove method in `IStudentResource`:

```
interface IStudentResource extends IResourceClass<IStudentDataModel> {
    deactivate(params: Object): IResource<IStudentDataModel>
    remove(params: Object): IResource<IStudentDataModel>
}
```

But compiler says:

> Interface 'IStudentResource' incorrectly extends interface
>   'IResourceClass'.   Types of property 'remove' are
>   incompatible.
>       Type '(data: Object) => IResource' is not assignable to type 'IResourceMethod'.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude but you can use a type assertion to **any** in order to make the type checking stop complaning.

```
return (<any>this.StudentResource.deactivate({ studnetId: studentId})).$promise;
```

Also since the typescript interfaces are open ended you can also amend the IResource interface to add the **$promise** property.

```html
interface IResourceClass<T> {
    $promise: IPromise<T>
}
```